# CSharp Preencher ComboBox com consulta, porém trazer já selecionada a opção salva no banco

Tags: c#, visual-studio, combobox

Tenho uma tela de cadastro de produto com um Combobox LOCAL. Tabela de produto possui o ID do LOCAL, chamado pro_local. E a tabela local os campos loc_cod e loc_descricao

Meu combobox é preenchido com a função:

```
public DataTable RetornaLocal()
    {
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = acessoDadosSqlServer.CriarConexao();
        sqlConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
        sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM local ORDER BY loc_descricao";

        SqlDataReader sqlDataReader = null;
        sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        dataTable.Load(sqlDataReader);
        return dataTable;

    }
```

No formulário de produto:

```
            cbLocal.DisplayMember = "loc_descricao";
            cbLocal.ValueMember = "loc_cod";
            cbLocal.DataSource = localNegocios.RetornaLocal();
```

Essas funções preenchem o combobox, mas quando trago o formulário produto para alterar esse produto, traz o combobox como se fosse uma inserção, não traz selecionado o pro_local salvo no banco. Como preencher um combobox com uma determinada ID no topo?

Att.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode simplesmente informar na propriedade `SelectedItem` o objeto que você deseja. Na resposta que você deu, você passa a propriedade `pro_local` para a propriedade `SelectedValue`. Se o objeto "produto" estiver contido no `DataTable` aunica coisa que você precisa fazer é `comboBox2.SelectedItem = produto;`. Eu costumo trabalhar com listas tipadas então nunca testei com `DataTable` mas acredito que seria o mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui setando no SelectedValue o campo produto.pro_local.
Como ficou:

```
        cbLocal.DisplayMember = "loc_descricao";
        cbLocal.ValueMember = "loc_cod";
        cbLocal.DataSource = localNegocios.RetornaLocal();
        cbLocal.SelectedValue = produto.pro_local ;
```